# Microsoft Azure how to get a list of locations from the REST ARM API?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Does Azure ARM REST API provide a way to get a list of available regions?

I can see that the classic REST API provides such a list as described here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg441293.aspx

But I can't see its equivalent for ARM.

Answer (score 4):

To list the locations for an Azure Subscription using ARM API, please see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790540.aspx.

However please keep in mind that not all resources are available in all locations. If you want to find out the locations where a particular resource type is available, you would need to fetch information about the provider of that resource  type. For this, please see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790524.aspx