# Get VMSize List from Azure for all locations

Tags: azure

Currently Azure exposes one API to fetch all of the VM Sizes. The API is dependent on a parameter i.e location.

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachinesizes/list)

> GET
>   https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/**{location}**/vmSizes?api-version=2017-12-01

Is there a way I can fetch all the VM Sizes without passing the location? i.e is there a way I can find out all the VM sizes irrespective of any location?
Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: No, this doesnt make sense, as some location dont have all the vms. if oyu are looking for a list of all possible vm sizes your best bet is documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first list the locations in the subscription.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/listlocations

Then for each location you list the VM sizes. You can keep track of duplicates yourself of VM sizes that exist in multiple locations.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachinesizes/list

You can see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544850/microsoft-azure-how-to-get-a-list-of-locations-from-the-rest-arm-api) for example of how to list locations.

Comment: Thanks!. But is there some URL which I can used to retrieve ALL VM sizes (not just specific to a location)? I don't want to send so many Http calls from my application just to retrieve a list of all possible VM sizes.

Comment: @Neelambuj what's your scenario? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a set of VM sizes which will be uploaded in my application via file upload. I am trying to validate whether the VM sizes are valid by calling the azure API. I dont want to call the API for each location. Rather, I want to make one call which will give me the list of all the vm sizes irrespective of any locaton. I will use this list for validation purpose.

Comment: But you only need to call this once, no? and keep it cached in memory or persist it.